# Connecting bluetooth to Lilypad Arduino

Tags: arduino, lilypad, bluetooth

How do i connect bluetooth to Lilypad Arduino?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Without knowing which BT module you are using it will be a little difficult to help, but. As mentioned above using the BlueSMiRF board and some jumper wires you can attach

- 5v to PWR
- (-) to GND
- tx to RX - I
- rx to TX - O

If you have a specific BT module you are working with update your question and we can try to be more helpful.